# Does anyone know anything on the history or any other information on this dagger?

Tags: identification, weapons, celtic

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Looking for information on this dagger: its history, value or anything anyone can provide.

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: Why do you assume it has any history?  And this is not the correct place to assess value; you're better served with an auction site.  Value changes due to fluctations in supply and demand. History.stackexchange tries to provide answers that are authoritative.

Comment: Are you looking for the type of dagger and if it was historically significant? Can we get a picture of the blade to see it's profile? Where did you get it? Do you have any back story on it? Something like "This was my grandfather's who served in Africa during WWII."

Comment: Also is the tang accessible? Usually, a bladesmith will mark their work there. It looks like the pommel is either a pin over or a threaded one. If it's threaded you should be able to unscrew the pommel. That would give us some very valuable information. (Don't break your blade though trying. If it's a screw off it should come off with just a little force)

Comment: There is no history associated with this, its a fantasy piece.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this piece is not historical and doesn't help the overall community.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a match with a visual search but the listing is [Here](https://www.milanuncios.com/otros-articulos-de-arte/daga-romana-381675001.htm). The description is "Daga Romana" or "Roman Dagar". One like it only different colored sheath was listed on the site and sold and has since been taken down. The site is based in Spain and looks like their version of Ebay. If I had to guess it's probably just a pretty dagger that you would find in a shop. With no real historic significance.

[image]

Comment: Thx for going in. To me, this looked like an eclectic mix of celtic, islamic, 'conanic' styles… If you could go into identifying these (or any other mixed, missed, misclassified etc., ))

Comment: When you say it's an eclectic mix of occidental and oriental styles, I am "in phase" with you: maybe it can come from Roman(i)a or could be **armenian** or from one of the other countries of Caucasus which have had islamic/turkish influence.

Comment: I would agree. I feel like there is definitely a mix of styles here. The shape of the handle, the guard and pummel look very Roman. If the dagger is as wide the sheath and same basic shape with a point that would also be fairly Roman. The markings though look Celtic, and the use of gems and the overall ornate nature looks Persian/middle eastern to me. Looking at the OP the pommel seems to be threaded (there is a gap there) to me that is more of a new age construction. typically when you have an old knife with a pommel you would see it pinned in place. The light brown also looks like plastic.

Comment: I do enjoy a good dagger though. Being an amateur bladesmith this really looks like knew (15 years or younger) construction. I would take a guess that we have a double edge, wide shallow fuller, down to a wide point. I'd really like to see the blade though.

Comment: Even as an amalgamate of collected, artificial & even random commercial hodgepodge; for this site, imo, the *max added value* would derive from binding back these allusions to historical precedents?  (Just an idea, perhaps too sweeping? @EvM The ID itself is on-topic enough.)

Comment: You can see the blade at https://www.milanuncios.com/otros-articulos-de-arte/daga-romana-381675001.htm. Just click at the photo and there are 4 more (or click at the { } ). It's mostly plastic. I think we call this dagger the equivalent to "mall ninja shit", so I wouldn't expect it to survive even the faintest strike.

Comment: @LаngLаngС. I can see your argument to keep it open at this point, like you said, it's an opinion. I voted to close based on the fact that there is no real history here. Like you said it's a combination of random cultural points but I don't think it deserves a delete because there is value in these points. The answers are valid and the discussion is worth keeping for reference.

Comment: @CarlosMartin good find. I searched and searched that site with those key words and could not pull it up. Thanks for the add.